# Difference between aura:method and events

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have a parent component and multiple child components created inside it through aura:iteration. On click of a button in outer/parent component, I want to  notify all child components and change their attributes. If I am not wrong, I can use call to aura:method as well as application event to achieve this where each child component would have an aura:method/event handler, correspondingly used. Which of the two would be better approach?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you provided a specific example. Typically when passing data from parent-to-child components the ideal is to set it in the child via an attribute. So I would say, unless there is some special circum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application events are really expensive .As a best practice it's recommended to avoid them unless you need them badly. It's reserved for something that's needed across the application.

aura:method is a great alternative .It keeps code readable and maintainable and there is less code needed .

Comment: Mohith - I've read in a couple places to avoid application events because they're expensive, but I'm curious in what way?  The app I'm developing makes heavy use of application events, but I've not noticed any performance degradation or anything like that.  This is my first browser-side development effort, and I assumed (dangerous, I know) there is way more than enough client-side computing power to handle application event processing.  Is the "expense" in using application events mainly UI response related, or is there some other aspect of them I might be missing?  Thanks!